# How to parse complextype in WSDL to get basic elements in it in Java?

Tags: java, wsdl, castor, complextype, wsdl4j

I have parsed wsdl files with the help of WSDL4J, JDOM and Castor libraries. Now, I can get the complex types but still can not access the elements in its sequence.

```
<xs:element name="AddInstanceGroupsResult">
    <xs:complexType>

        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation><![CDATA[
              <p>Output from an AddInstanceGroups call.</p>
           ]]></xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>

      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="JobFlowId" type="tns:XmlStringMaxLen256" minOccurs="0">

          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation><![CDATA[
                <p>The job flow ID in which the instance groups are added.</p>
             ]]></xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>

        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="InstanceGroupIds" type="tns:InstanceGroupIdsList" minOccurs="0">

          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation><![CDATA[
                <p>Instance group IDs of the newly created instance groups.</p>
             ]]></xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>

        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

For example, I can reach AddInstanceGroupsResult as a complex type, but I can not get the basic elements in it (JobFlowId and InstanceGroupIds)..

```
case Structure.MODELGROUP:
Group modelGroup = (Group)ct;
ContentModelGroup contentModel = modelGroup.getContentModelGroup();
int count = contentModel.getParticleCount();
for (int n=0; n< count; n++){
    ElementDecl elementDecl2 = (ElementDecl)contentModel.getParticle(n);


    result.add(elementDecl2.getName());
    resultLong.add(parseParameterName(elementDecl2.getName()));
    resultType.add(elementDecl2.getType().getName());
```

}

Any suggestions? Thanks..

Comment: did you find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do something like:

```
Sequence seq = ct.getSequence();
```

Then once you've done that you can get the elements in that sequence like you would for the elements in the Complex Type itself i.e.

```
for(Element el : seq.getElements())
{
     //do stuff
}
```